# How can I enable Google Code Prettify linenums in SO syntax highlighting markup?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting does not say whether or how this is supported.

I have not found anything about line numbering in [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) either.

This would be a great feature to have to correlate error message line numbers with code samples.

Support for a line number offset would be good too, so that code excerpts will suffice.

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted#Line_Numbering has the offset support too.